# Exporting an environment from an R package

Tags: r, mongodb, devtools, proto, testthat

I am developing an R package that wraps the `rmongodb` package and creates a developer-friendly interface for working with MongoDB. The package uses `proto` internally.

I'd like to export a single factory method via a proto object (an environment) called `MongoDB`, whose definition is:

```
MongoDB <- proto(
  new = function(., ...) {
    # Good stuff in here...
  }
)
```

During development with RStudio & `devtools` and during local testing this does not seem to be a problem. However, I am experiencing several problems:

- `devtools::check()` insists on putting an `import(MongoDB)` in my NAMESPACE file which makes `R CMD check` fail with "Namespace dependency not required: 'MongoDB'".
- When I remove this import directive, `R CMD check` fails with "object 'MongoDB' not found" while running my `testthat` tests, even if I manually add `export(MongoDB)`. However, `devtools::test()` works fine in RStudio.

What is the recommended way of exporting `proto` objects, which are environments, from R packages?

**Update:**

Per Gabor's suggestion below, I've made sure that [`MongoDB.Rd`](http://pastie.org/5566930) declares `MongoDB` as data (the link has the source). I still get a failure in `MongoDB` not being visible in the tests (which use `testthat`). My `DESCRIPTION` file is [here](http://pastie.org/5566937) and `NAMESPACE` is [here](http://pastie.org/5566940).

Comment: You may want to look at the [`RMongo`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/index.html) package as well .. it uses the Java driver and has a higher level interface than the `rmongodb` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Specify `export("MongoDB")` in your `NAMESPACE` file to make the `MongoDB` proto object publicly available.
2. Specify `LazyData: yes` in your `DESCRIPTION` file so that it automatically loads when accessed.
3. Add an `.Rd` file documenting it as a dataset.

It should then pass `R CMD check` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Gabor. I still fail `check` for the same reason: `MongoDB` cannot be found when loading the tests. I've updated the question with links to the `Rd` files, `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: @Sim, I have created packages using the 3 points I mentioned and they worked so this is likely a problem with the development environment you are using and not R. You might need to take it up with the maintainer(s) of those tools.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: since the problem shows up with the tests, are you suggesting that I raise the issue with @hadley and see if it is about `testthat` (where the tests are) or `devtools` (which emits potentially wrong instructions in `NAMESPACE`)?

Answer (score 1):

This directive :

```
import(MongoDB)
```

means that you import the `MongoDB` namespace  into your package. Probably not what you want if i understand correctly.

I think you want to export the `MongoDB` object, then

```
export(MongoDB)
```

should work fine.

Comment: Right. The `import` statement is inserted by `devtools`, which is not cool. Alas, `export(MongoDB)` does not work.